# How to use Partial generic for rest parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, partial

Can anyone explain why the below code won't work ?

```js
type D<P> = P extends unknown[] ? (...a: Partial<P>) => void : never;
// => A rest parameter must be of an array type.ts(2370)
```

But this line works:

```js
type D<P extends unknown[]> = (...a: Partial<P>) => void;
```

And further, this one line won't work:

```js
type D<P extends unknown[]> = P extends [unknown, ...unknown[]] ? (...a: Partial<P>) => void;
// A rest parameter must be of an array type.ts(2370)
```

Comment: This feels like an inconsistency in the compiler.  My instinct is that `Partial<P>` where `P extends unknown[]` is not guaranteed to be an array (while `Partial<[1,2,3]>` is `[1?, 2?, 3?]`, something like `Partial<Foo>` where `class Foo extends Array<number> {a=1}` is not an array), which means they should both be an error (as per https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45488).  But obviously the second example is not giving an error. 

Comment: The other relevant issue seems to be https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29919.  I don't know if anyone in the TS team has noticed or responded to the inconsistency yet.  Someone (you?) might want to [file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose) a bug report showing the first two examples and that the expected behavior is that both succeed or both fail.